# Are all Reed's costumes elastic?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-four-2

After I started watching *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer*, I understood there is something wrong about Reed. All costumes don't tear after he stretches, and I've already seen several of these costumes. Here is it:

[image][image][image]

Even his wedding suit doesn't tear!

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you open to answers from the Marvel comic books, or film-continuity only?

Comment: @Thunderforge As you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't recall that this is specifically mentioned in this movie but *in the comics* Reed creates clothing from

### Unstable Molecules

> A synthetic material created/discovered by the famous scientist Reed Richards, which can be altered easily and adapt to a certain environment, allowing them to be incredibly resilient to drastic changes in heat, cold, pressure, density, dirt, etc. making them ideal for use as superhero costumes.
>
> Unstable Molecules are configuration of unknown atomic nuclei and electrons discovered or synthesized by Reed Richards, which is responsive to certain energized matter around it. Used in the making of clothing for the Fantastic Four and certain other superhuman beings, unstable molecular cloth mimics its wearer's physical properties, it can turns invisible like The Invisible Woman, allowing it to stretch like Mister Fantastic and burst into flame without burning like the Human Torch.
>
> <sup>[**Wikia**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_Molecules)</sup>

As it happens, this **is** mentioned in the first *Fantastic Four* [**movie script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/fantasticfour.html)...

> ```
>                               REED (CONT'D)
>                      Material made from self-regulating
>                      unstable molecules.  I've been working
>                      on a formula for this.
> ```

[image]

Comment: So Reed used molecules to create his wedding costume... interesting.

Comment: @VerNick Well, everybody uses molecules to create their clothes. *Unstable* molecules are far rarer, and yes, it does seem that Reed Richards in the habit of making all of his clothes out of the stuff.